# List all Linux servers where my account was created

Tags: linux, scripting

I'm a new Linux sys. admin (in the past, Windows sysadmin)
We have 400 and more Linux servers. 
On some servers my account is create and on some not.
I want to know wich server I have to ask for creating my account.

I try to find a script to list all the server where my account is not created.
Tx.

Comment: you could try to connect to them all using something like ansible and check the answers

Comment: If you need to create an account on 400 servers, you are doing something *very* wrong.

Comment: `ansible -m ping` here you go

Comment: Tx folk. The "ansible -m ping" gonna return for echea servers the result of the ping, right? But I want to test if my account exist. Someting like "ansible ssh "listHostFile" but I don't want to keep open my session where my account exist... (my account is created about 20% on our server). Which exactly Ansible command do I have to run? (I know it basic for you guys but i'm starting...) Tx.

Answer (score 0):

if you have access to the servers via ssh
you may use simple bash script to check acces (if connected - login exist)

```
    #!/bin/sh
    file=hostfile
    while read line
    do
    echo "$line\n"
    ssh -t -T you_user_name@$line bash -c "'sudo uptime'" < /dev/null
    #or grep username in passwd file:
    ssh -t -T you_user_name@$line bash -c "'sudo grep you_username /etc/passwd'" < /dev/null
    echo "\n"
    done < $file
```

where hostname -  file contained hostname or ip address per line:

```
hostname1
hostname2
192.168.1.1
```